# Parsing date and time in python

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, tuples

I am trying to create a column that grabs just the date (ie 2004-03-18) from a column in the same dataframe.  The datetime expression starts with the date (year-month-day), the letter 'T' and then the time expression.  For example, "2004-03-18T07:00:00", and I am just wanting "2004-03-18" portion of the datetime.

```
dt = datetime.now()
UAT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(UAT['Date']).dt.date
UAT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(UAT['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

The above code gets the following error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which line does that error occurred? I can't reproduce your error with the code that you provide

Comment: It happens at the second line 'UAT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(UAT['Date']).dt.date'

Comment: The UAT['Date'] currently has dtype = object.  Not sure if that is my issue..?

Comment: how did you initialize the Date column?

Comment: I imported the data using pandas using 'read_excel' function, and the column comes in as an object.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to convert the column type to `'datetime64[ns]` with `astype()` function, then you can retrieve just the date part of the datetimes string using `date()` function

```
UAT['Date'] = UAT['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
UAT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(UAT['Date']).dt.date
UAT['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(UAT['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: The converting to `datetime64[ns]` worked but I am still getting the same error on the second line `pd.to_datetime(date).dt.date`.